# Custom Searchbox for vue-table-2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-tables-2

Using Vue Table 2, I do not want to use the default search/filter input and the  Records drop down.  I.e. I do not want to use controls in the image below:
[image: screenshot of the default search control]

Instead, I want to create my own input box outside the table.  I am able to hide the default row containing the image above.  However, after adding my own input box - example:

```
    <input type="text" v-model="searchTerm" v-on:keyup='filterResult()' />,
```

How can I trigger the filter event to process my filter request in the `filterResult()` method?

```
 data(){
        return {
            searchTerm:'',
            customFilters: [{
                name: 'mysearch',
                callback: function (row, query) {
                    return row.name[0] == query;
                }
            }],
        },
    },
    methods:{
        filterResult(){
           //how to trigger event to filter result using the searchTerm
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you perhaps read the [docs](https://matanya.gitbook.io/vue-tables-2/custom-filters) on custom filters?

Comment: Yes I did and I have tried tons of example.  I tried using custom filter but this too didn't work.

Comment: Can you post some of these attempts so we can help you investigate?

Comment: I added a custom search, but how do you trigger the custom search?

Answer (score 1):

Given a table definition like this, where `tableoptions` its an object containing the options you are applying to your table(these have to match their documentation), in this case i'm only adding `customFilters`, but you might have `columns`, `headings` or others

```html
<v-client-table :options="tableoptions">
</v-client-table>
```

In their [documentation](https://matanya.gitbook.io/vue-tables-2/custom-filters) it says that you should use this to trigger the custom filter

```
Event.$emit('vue-tables.filter::alphabet', query);
```

But it fails to say that `Event` it's `VueTables.Event`, so you will need to update your js to the following:

```js
data() {
    return {
      searchTerm: '',
      tableoptions: {
        customFilters: [{
          name: 'mysearch',
          callback: function(row, query) {
            //this should be updated to match your data objects
            return row.name[0] == query; 
          }
        }]
      },
    },
  },
  methods: {
    filterResult() {
      VueTables.Event.$emit('vue-tables.filter::mysearch', query);
    }
  }
```

Comment: any idea how can we do this on v-server-table ?